# My Invalid and valid date code does not show

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans, date

I am suppose to program a code to check whether the date is valid  However my issue is over here is with the output. I am unable to display out if the user has input a valid/invalid date or month. T

```
    String date;

   int dd,mm,yyyy;

   boolean leapyear,validdate;




   if(mm >=1 || mm <=12) // to check if user input month which is less than 1 or more than 12
   {
       System.out.println(mm+" is an invalid month");
   }
   if((mm == 4 || mm == 6 || mm == 9 || mm == 11) && (dd <= 30)) // months with 30 days
        {
            validdate = true;
            System.out.println(mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy + " is a valid date.");
        }

        //For months with 31 days
       else if((mm == 1 || mm == 3 || mm== 5 || mm == 7 || mm == 8 || mm == 10 || mm == 12) && (dd <= 31))
        {
            validdate = true;
            System.out.println(mm + "/"+ dd + "/" + yyyy + " is a valid date.");

        }

    else
       {

      System.out.println("Invalid date!");

   }




  }
}
```

}

Comment: Lets start with indenting your code properly. Also pay attention to amount of braces and their placement.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(mm >=1 || mm <=12)
```

should be

```
if (mm < 1 || mm > 12)
```

Otherwise **every** value of `mm` will evaluate to `true` making the date "invalid".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking each individual filed (year, month and day) manually you can always use `LocalDatea.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`. For example:

```
LocalDate date;

try {
  date = LocalDate.of(yyyy, mm, dd);
} catch(java.time.DateTimeException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

It will throw an exception if date is invalid:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2018,2,31);
|  java.time.DateTimeException thrown: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'
|        at LocalDate.create (LocalDate.java:459)
|        at LocalDate.of (LocalDate.java:271)
|        at (#3:1)
```

Comment: I see,however my assignment stated that I am only allowed to use if else statement